# Missing larger/smaller option for Windows Live Tile

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am referring to [App tiles and badges sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/app-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148)

By running the sample, and right click on the icon, I realize I can have larger/smaller option.

[image]

However, for my own project, I cannot find such option.

[image: App tiles and badges sample]

I go through all settings in the project sample but unable to figure out differences. I would like to have my project having larger/smaller option. Is there anything I had missed out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a Wide Logo image (310 x 150 pixels) in the app manifest:

[image: The app manifest page]

Answer (score 2):

I think your referring to live tiles.
If your using a live tile you can add multiple definitions at once.  One must be large and one must be small to support both.

Here is the xml for each one, to add two just add another node under binding:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx

example with both:

```
      string image = String.Format("<tile>" +
                                        "<visual>" +

                                            "<binding template=\"TileWidePeekImageCollection06\">" +

                                                "<image id=\"1\" src=\"ms-appx:///Assets/mainApp_large_icon.png\" alt=\"alt text\"/>" +
                                                "<image id=\"2\" src=\"ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png\" alt=\"alt text\"/>" +
                                                "<image id=\"3\" src=\"ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png\" alt=\"alt text\"/>" +
                                                "<image id=\"4\" src=\"ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png\" alt=\"alt text\"/>" +
                                                "<image id=\"5\" src=\"ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png\" alt=\"alt text\"/>" +
                                                "<image id=\"6\" src=\"ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png\" alt=\"alt text\"/>" +
                                                "<text id=\"1\">mytext</text>" +

                                            "</binding>" +

                                            "<binding template=\"TileSquarePeekImageAndText04\">" +
                                                "<image id=\"1\" src=\"ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png\" alt=\"alt text\"/>" +
                                                "<text id=\"1\">testtext</text>" +
                                            "</binding>" +

                                        "</visual>" +
                                      "</tile>");
```